# Fully customized client side data validation

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a custom solution for data validation that is server based.
When updating data my code will first validate by calling the database (sp) and returning any reason why data might not be correct to update or create. I plan to do this with a string of error codes.
Next, I will load into a viewbag related messages that can be displayed in the view. The custom messages are coming from the database and can be updated by the admin. Further, the custom messages are stored in multiple languages. For this reason, I think the best way to do this is have them in the database.

The question is, can I do something like this by preloading the messages in the viewbag and do some validation on the client based on this viewbag?

Not all datavalidation is possible on client site. (e.g. check if a name is unique). But certain datavalidation would not require the server (empty textbox).

The current system is developed in ASP.NET Core MVC on Microsoft SQL db

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve client side validation by adding below scripts to your application. This is know as **unobtrusive validation**. Tag helpers and HTML helpers use validation attributes of model properties and render as `data-` attribute. Jquery unobtrusive validation parses the `data-` attribute and does client side validation.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

You can display error:

```
<span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Also, you can check name unique or not using `[Remote]` attribute.

```
[Remote(action: "CheckUniqueName", controller: "Home")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```